# Restangular Calling REST Service causing TypeError: Cannot set property 'route' of null

Tags: angularjs, rest

I am using restangular in my AngularJS application to fetch records from REST Servives.

I am calling the REST Service like below:

```
$scope.students = function()
{
    $scope.studentsGet = ListService.getList($cookieStore.get('baseUrl'), 'students/reference/1', null,null);
    $scope.studentsGet.then(function(data) {
    $scope.students = data.list;
  });
}
```

But, I am getting this error

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'route' of null
    at restangularizeBase (http://localhost:8080/Students/app/lib/restangular.js:638:56)
    at restangularizeElem (http://localhost:8080/Students/app/lib/restangular.js:788:35)
    at http://localhost:8080/Students/app/lib/restangular.js:882:38
    at http://localhost:8080/Students/app/lib/lodash.js:3877:29
    at eval (eval at createIterator (http://localhost:8080/Students/app/lib/lodash.js:1778:21), <anonymous>:20:9)
    at Function.map (http://localhost:8080/Students/app/lib/lodash.js:3876:9)
    at http://localhost:8080/Students/app/lib/restangular.js:878:45
    at deferred.promise.then.wrappedCallback (http://localhost:8080/Students/app/lib/angular/angular.js:10689:81)
    at deferred.promise.then.wrappedCallback (http://localhost:8080/Students/app/lib/angular/angular.js:10689:81)
    at http://localhost:8080/Students/app/lib/angular/angular.js:10775:26
```

Where it is causing the issue. Help me.

Comment: Are you sure you got ListService injected into the controller?

Comment: Yes, I have injected service in the controller

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are using `getList()` method incorrectly. I'm not sure what exactly is your `ListService` but I'd assume it's custom Restangular service (https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#how-to-create-a-restangular-service-with-a-different-configuration-from-the-global-one)

In that case you should rather set base path inside the service config (not inside `getList()` method:

```
app.factory('ListService', function(Restangular) {
  return Restangular.withConfig(function(RestangularConfigurer) {
    RestangularConfigurer.setBaseUrl($cookieStore.get('baseUrl'));
  });
});
```

Then, after you inject `ListService` in the controller you can use something like:

```
$scope.studentsGet = function() {
    ListService.all('students/reference/1').getList().then(function(data){
         $scope.students = data.list;
    });
}
```

So, first you have to create Restangular object, that is a pointer to the element or a collection (this is what `one` and `all` methods do respectively, when you pass them a `route` argument). Then you can call `getList()` on that object.

**Edit:**
In case your `ListService` is decoupled Restangular Service (https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#decoupled-restangular-service) that would mean it is already an Restangular object, which you can call `getList()` method on.

```
module.factory('ListService', function(Restangular) {
  return Restangular.service('list');
});

ListService.getList() // this will make call to http://base.url/list
ListService.getList('students', {type: all}) // thill will make call to http://base.url/list/students?type=all
```

Comment: thanks for reply. I found the issue, I am getting 'null' value in my json response for one field.